# Which programming/markup language is this?

Tags: windows, markup

I'm working on a game with a team and I'm new to their project.

They are using an own engine which is programmed by a separate guy which is the leader of the team. He sent me the game project and the engine. He is 2 weeks away and I should start to program basic player movement.

The scripting is in C# and Lua and that's okay for me but often I see weird "script" file in the project folder, next to the game code. I'm not sure what this is? It's not xml nor json. Does anybody know what language this is? I can't ask him because he is away.

This "code" was in a file called scenery_backstream_bstr.cac:

```
#CAC startdoc __lenver##__kestd%BASEVER?1.0
&GVAR __kestd%GENGRP{ #CAC(BCKSTR}            </ BASE PARTITION\>
{
    5e24f2b0c52ffc549a40583c2a44082e
    425bc050294b7dd9ac428da5bcc8cffe 
    3c681b7f4513938488f0a61556f34f3e
    82100e8b272a6ebf4cc052178fbf55b9
    d0b7e6ee96f6fdf853ee9795d02e97fb
} __strideof(GENGRP{#CAC(BCKSTR)}} **: (0xff) ? 0xff = 0 {
__kestd_drawbucket
{
    SHADERPARTITION_0x0##GEN_REFLCETION
    {
        UNIM##((0x) ?? 0xff $ HLS_D3DBCSTR) == $AS_BASEPOINTER ? § : ^;          </ IF DRAWBUCKET IS UNLOADED GET THE BASE POINTER OR NULL (§)\>
        {
            144b1cd49af1
            3c2ae146eb51
            2b2cf74be189
            7a31fa2061f9
            980376b28884
            b88694dac0ed
            dbb36cc7c931
            d7a6fb3b98cb
            81559847891d
            fbbad67448bb
            1bf499e6f357
            083a7f0c8ce5
            610e6d34a2ab
            f242419f11b7
            fdbbd067898c
            01eee4a57d91
            46a1cf49c308
            dc33149a6783
            2c77813db5fa
            a9dbe5b6d114
            5407cf314ec7
            d5c687ede619
            15a2dcfa6e4d
            96a551aa3b14
            e48cf48c74a9
            1258c03dca75
            53bc36a37f2c
            260639258063
            dd4d19659f93
            932865eebc57
            917dd4af7c1c
            f98d9849201f
            542b441d95da
            4d338c35cb23
            094b2055f213
            bae9ddf89d22
            84476019ab95
            7b6f036a1f58
            759284affea7
            01232cad190e
            c3a63151b473
            6f7fafee368c
            f5f76ebe20bf
            e18e59e4e259
            e13840a2f414
            f7db178cbbb6
            d253d62c5221
            beb0d2bafd03
            32acb34255b0
            08fed326a21b
            0b0c9a03e719
            b72f71bfb5d4
            0e7f863f0596
            050d7f3aaefb
            84e28725c90d
            c6b297e05d47
            86102bf15a96
            b0d3383844ad
            0376ec0759bc
            e921dd5728da
            df0aa7a863f4
            f20347d37745
            91e1ee783163
            23649ec06a1e

        }
    }
}
}
#CAC endscript AS##(;)- (OK(§)(){ 0xff}
```

Comment: May be a programming language or data store format developed by himself?

Comment: Sure could be possible - this guy is a real pro i mean he writes a whole engine with editor alone. But why shoulnd he use a common format like json or xml :/ I hope i dont have to write these files :)

Comment: Because sometimes you need a _specified_ data compress algorithm (that special method can compress far better than normal method), or a _specified_ programming language for special usage (for example, DSL, or something "smarter").

Comment: **TYPO** alerts: it's spelled correctly **which** (not "wich"), and it's a **language** - not a "languane".....

Comment: Im sorry english is not my mother language :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok it has been answered there was a txt file explaining all file types.
Cac is the a engine format and this is a file which contains indices which material has which shader in a scene. A drawbucket is here called a shader with resources.
Alright so it wasn't a public language.

Thanks anyways :)